# jquery animate div with mouseenter and mouseleave

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

I'm trying to create a menu where the item that the mouse is over slides to the right. After the mouse leaves, I want the div to move back to its original position. Right now, when I mouse over, the div moves to the right, but when I mouse out, it just stays there and doesn't move back to the left.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".menu_option").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".menu_option").animate({left:'50px'});
  });
  $(".menu_option").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".menu_option").animate({right:'50px'});
  });
});
</script>
```

css looks like this

```
.menu_option {
height: 50px;
width: 150px;
position: relative;
}
.menu_holder {
float: left;
height: 300px;
width: 150px;
position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu_holder">
<div class="menu_option">Content for  class "menu_one" Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could you post up a http://jsfiddle.net with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mouse leave you should use

```
$('.menu_option').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.menu_option').animate({left : 0});
});
```

Comment: Well, of course now all the menu item with that name move at once. Is there an easy way to get each div with that class to run the animation separately, or do I need to give each its own class name?

Comment: Yes there is just use `$(".menu_option").mouseleave(function(event) { $(event.currentTarget).animate({left:0}) });`